# I can't access to data from MySql server using the IP of router

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, localhost

In this image, I use localhost in the URL and I get the DATA from my server. The selected numbers come with this `SQL query >> SELECT Count (*) FROM TABLENAME`.

[image: oij]

But when I use the IP address of the router, I can access the server but there is no data from the server. You can see that there is a difference between the first image and the second.

[image: oij]

Some help please, thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the DB Connection string pointing to database correctly and there are rows in tables

Comment: Thank for your help